# How mongoose schema relates to db in CRUD operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How does fetching records from mongoose `find()` and updating records with `updateOne` work exactly.

I am unable to find it on social media..
When a `GET` request arrived to route handler. Will data fetch from db and  maps to schema or will it get records directly from db?

Please explain the proper workflow. What happen when request arrives and how the mapping from db to schema works in CRUD?

Comment: Hi Vishwas, the workflow is entirely up to the code you implement. Mongoose doesn't map to a GET request for you. Do you have some example code in relation to the question? or is it a general question about how you can map a GET request to  mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the assumption that you are also using a framework like [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/), a `GET` request does not go directly to `mongodb`

within a framework like express, you write a handler to handle `GET`/`POST`/`PATCH`/`DELETE`/`PUT` etc. within each of those routes you would write your code to interact with mongoose (mongodb)

for reference here is a
[basic entry level NODEJS app](https://github.com/alilland/nodejs-api)